# Web Service para vários bancos de dados

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou começando com Node.js e queria saber se alguém poderia me dar uma força na questão de fazer um Web Service para vários bancos de dados.

Já tenho um código desenvolvido para o MySQL, estou precisando implementar no mesmo código para os bancos de dados Sql Server e Sqlite.

Se alguém tiver algumas dicas de como eu poderia fazer isso.